# Correct way of storing many-to-many SQL relation when intersection is often required?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have a growing list of machines, each connected to a different type of equipment and can do different things, and I'm trying to build some sort of queuing system for that. My first idea so far is to use a database table `machines` storing the available machines, from which I'll be able to select required machines based on a specified capabilities. So the table would look something like this:

`machineId    machineName    status    equipment1    equipment2    network1    network2
     1        Test            FREE         0             1            1            0`

Where the code would have a list of parameters, and execute a code searching for all of them. For example executing `SELECT * FROM Machines WHERE equipment2=1 AND network1=1 AND network2=0 AND status LIKE 'FREE'`.

This works in theory, but has two problems I would like to avoid:

1. Each field needs to be defined in the code, when adding a new column as well
2. Some fields are mutually exclusive. I.E I don't want a computer connected to network 2 to run some of the tests in some situations, and some equipment prevents the machine from doing some basic functionality (even those that don't require and equipment), so I must add in the code a specific exclusion for it. E.G. `AND network2=0` above.

My next idea was to use a Junction Table. So the tables would be:

`Machines:
machineId    machineName    status`

`Equipments:
equipemntId    equipmentName    exclusive`

And then I'll have a junction table

`MachinesEquipments:
machineId    equipmentId`

But then if I want a machine which has `equipment2` and access to `network1`, but doesn't have access to `network2` (since it's marked exclusive), and is also `FREE`, it gets too complicated for me to know how to do it, or even if it's the correct way to...

Is this the correct way for that many-to-many? Which SQL pieces am I missing?

Comment: Where is "network" stored in your data model?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff It is a type of equipment as far as I'm concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second, normalized version is the right way to go.  You can resolve your queries using a `having` clause (perhaps with a `where` clause as well).  For your example, the query is something like this:

```
select m.machineid
from machines m join
     machinesequipment me
     on me.machineid = m.machineid join
     equipment e
     on me.equipmentid = e.equipementid
where m.status = 'free'
group by m.machineid
having sum(e.equipmentname = 'equipment1') > 0 and   -- has "equipment1
       sum(e.equipmentname = 'equipment2') = 0;      -- does not have "equipment2"
```

I don't know how `network` is stored in this model, but including it is probably just a simple tweak on this query.

For networks, you can add additional clauses such as:

```
sum(e.equipmentname = 'network1') > 0
```

to handle the networks.